# Call Function from other class

Tags: android, class, chat, installation

I'm making an android app using the BluetoothChat example.

I need to separate de bluetooth config activity from the chat activity, so, I've got a main activity with the buttons to enable/discoverable the bluetooth, and another button to go to the chat activity.

The functions are the same than in the example, but i have divided them in 2 activities.

The thing is that i need to call to the SetupChat () function from the main activity, to call to this function when the bluetooth is enabled. But I've got this function in the Chat activity because there are other variables in this activity that depend of it.

So, how can I call this function from the main activity??

I've readed some methods. If the function would be static i could call it without problems, but it is a public void. I cant neither put this function in a simple class because it calls the "findviewbyid" function and it needs to be in a activity.

So, how can I call it?

I incorpore booth activities here:

This is the MainActivity:

```
public class BTActivity extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton1);
    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton2);
    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton4);
    final Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton5);

    button5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            lanzarComunicacion (null);
        }
    });


    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LanzarBusqueda(null);

        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "MAKING YOUR DEVICE DISCOVERABLE";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();

                Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
                discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);

                startActivity(discoverableIntent);
            }
        }
    });

    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();

            //out.append("TURN_OFF BLUETOOTH");
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "TURNING_OFF BLUETOOTH";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, 15);
            toast.show();

        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
    else {
        //HERE IS THE FIRST PLACE WHERE IT IS CALLED
        if (mTransmission == null) BTCommunication.setupChat();
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                connectDevice(data);
            }
        case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session  
                //HERE IS CALLED                
                //BTCommunication.setupChat();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occurred
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            break;
    }

}


private void connectDevice(Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LLEGA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Get the device MAC address
    String address = data.getExtras().getString(DeviceListDialog.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
    // Get the BluetoothDevice object
    BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
    // Attempt to connect to the device
    mTransmission.connect(device);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bt, menu);
    return true;
}


/** Intent de llamada a activity de comunicacion*/
public void lanzarComunicacion (View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, BTCommunication.class);
    startActivity(i);
}

/** Intent de llamada a dialogo de busqueda de dispositivos*/
public void LanzarBusqueda (View view) {
    Intent serverintent = new Intent(this, DeviceListDialog.class);
    startActivityForResult(serverintent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
}
```

}

/ This is the Chat Activity:

```
public class BTCommunication extends Activity {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat);

    // Performing this check in onResume() covers the case in which BT was
    // not enabled during onStart(), so we were paused to enable it...
    // onResume() will be called when ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE activity returns.
    if (mTransmission != null) {
        // Only if the state is STATE_NONE, do we know that we haven't started already
        if (mTransmission.getState() == Transmission.STATE_NONE) {
            // Start the Bluetooth chat services
            mTransmission.start();
        }
    }
}



public void setupChat() {
    // Initialize the array adapter for the conversation thread
    mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message);
    mConversationView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.in);
    mConversationView.setAdapter(mConversationArrayAdapter);

    // Initialize the compose field with a listener for the return key
    mOutEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mOutEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(mWriteListener);

    // Initialize the send button with a listener that for click events
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Send a message using content of the edit text widget
            TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
    });

    // Initialize the Transmission to perform bluetooth connections
    mTransmission = new Transmission(this, mHandler);

    // Initialize the buffer for outgoing messages
    mOutStringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the Bluetooth chat services
    if (mTransmission != null) mTransmission.stop();
}


/**
 * Sends a message.
 * @param message  A string of text to send.
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mTransmission.getState() != Transmission.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mTransmission.write(send);

        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

// The action listener for the EditText widget, to listen for the return key
private final TextView.OnEditorActionListener mWriteListener = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the action is a key-up event on the return key, send the message
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_NULL && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            String message = view.getText().toString();
            sendMessage(message);
        }
        return true;
    }
};



private final void setStatus(int resId) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(resId);
}

private final void setStatus(CharSequence subTitle) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setSubtitle(subTitle);
}



// The Handler that gets information back from the Transmission
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                    case Transmission.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                        mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                        break;
                    case Transmission.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                        break;
                    case Transmission.STATE_LISTEN:
                    case Transmission.STATE_NONE:
                        setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the buffer
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                break;
            case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                // save the connected device's name
                mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

}

Comment: You can call another activity from the main one, by using `Intents`, check this one : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: If you like to have an example of this, paste the names of the two Activity classes here and I'll give you an example.

Comment: Code Added in the question. The main activity is called "BTActivity". The second activity where the Public void SetupChat() is is called "BTCommunication"

Comment: Try this: `public class BTActivity extends BTCommunication` and try to call the `SetupChat()` directly - see if it works in your case.

Comment: Too many problems doing it this way. Isn't there another way to do it? Maybe setting the SetupChat() function in another class and calling it form BTComunnication? The problem is that I don'r know how to do it

Comment: Then declare the function as `public static void setupChat()` and call it in the `Activity` `BTActivity` with: `BTComunnication.setupChat();`.

Comment: Yes, I've tryed that way, but it makes some errors like "Cannot use this in a static context" refering to mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.message); And "Cannot make a static reference to the non static method findviewbyide"

Comment: For the first error -> `ArrayAdapter<String> mConversationArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.message);`. For the second error go like that-> In the function put `getActivity().` after each cast like: `EditText mOutEditText = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);`.

Comment: Solved declaring all variables in a new file, and cutting the "Handler" function and part of the "setupChat" code to the main activity. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Normally, i have two ways to handle this.

1. mainacvitity offer a public static instance
2. use a manager class to hold instance of mainacvitity